# Unable to create a new registry after a certain point in the structure

Tags: c++, registry

Hi,

I am currently trying to create an application that can disable/enable the options from the ctrl+alt+del menu in windows 7.

This is a snippet of code, it's hardcoded to remove the Task Manager:

```
HKEY hkey;
DWORD dwDisposition;
bool ok = false;
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System"), 0, NULL, 0, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hkey, &dwDisposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    DWORD rofl = 1;
    if (RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("DisableTaskMgr"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&rofl, sizeof(DWORD)) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        ok = true;
    }
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
}
```

For example, if I try to create this registry in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion* or any other folder, everything works fine. But as soon as I try to enter *Policies*, the RegCreateKeyEx function does not return *ERROR_SUCCES*.

Since, that's the location where I need to put that registry in order to remove Task Manager option, I'm wondering why can't I acces that folder?

**PS** If I run the following reg file, the registry is created and the Task Manager option is removed, so I'm guessing I have the necessary rights:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]"DisableTaskMgr"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Have you tried running the application (explicitly) as administrator to see if that gives you the necessary rights?

Comment: Did you run this from an elevated prompt? I expect UAC will prevent you access to this.

Comment: thanks, starting the application from an elevated prompt works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call (with these exact parameters) returns **code 5** which stands for **insufficient permissions** (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED), as you have guessed yourself. Try running the application as administrator if you haven't already.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, starting the application from an elevated prompt works just fine.